# How to add a table after abstract in LaTex

Tags: tables, abstract

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,number]{elsarticle}
```

I need to add a table after the abstract in the document.

I am trying the below syntax, but the table is placed in the first page.

```
\begin {abstract}
some text
\end{abstract}

   \begin{table}[!t]
%\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\caption{Nomenclature}\label{nom}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{A. Sets}}\\
\\
$S$ &Set of suppliers\\
$T$ &Set of time periods\\
$J$ &Set of customers\\
$L$ &Set of levels\\
$K$ &Set of attributes\\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: replace table placing option `[!t]` with `[!ht]`.

Comment: is it really necessary to use the `table` environment?  why not simply use `tabular` with a caption from one of the separate caption-related packages?

Answer (score 2):

- please always provide small, but complete example of the document, which show your roblem
- solution to your problem i already give you in my comment below of question: placing option `[!t]` with `[!ht]`

example of (small but complete document) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,number]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum*[11]
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
   \begin{table}[!ht]
%\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\caption{Nomenclature}\label{nom}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} l}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{A. Sets}}\\
\\
S & Set of suppliers\\
T & Set of time periods\\
J & Set of customers\\
L & Set of levels\\
K & Set of attributes\\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]